# How to get the correct original purchase and expires date in IAP Swift

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I am currently testing In app purchases in the sandbox to see if the user subscription is currently active or expired. I just subscribed for one month and the receipt says the subscription is expired straight away. The orginalPurchaseDate and ExpiryDate both look wrong. How can i determine which dates in json gotten back are the right ones. I compare the expiryDate to the original purchase date to determine is subscription is still active.

```
func checkIfSubscriptionIsActive() {
    IAPManager.shared.validatePurchaseReceipt { (pReceipt) in
        self.receipt = pReceipt
        let expiryDate = self.receipt.last.map { $0.expiresDate}!.skTodate
        let originalPurchaseDate = self.receipt.last.map { $0.originalPurhaseDate}!.skTodate
        print("Latest Receipt: \(self.receipt.last)")
        if expiryDate?.compare(originalPurchaseDate!) == .orderedDescending {
            print("Subscription is expired")
        } else {
            print("Subscription is still active")
        }
    }
}
```

Here my logs

> > Latest Receipt: Optional(Vinylly.IAPReceiptInfo(quantity: "1", tansactionID: "1000000500500768", productID: "com.myApp.skLLC.autoRenewableSubscription", originalPurhaseDate: "2019-01-17 11:50:53 Etc/GMT", isTrialPeriod: "false", webOrderLineItem: "1000000042609588", expiresDate: "2019-02-06 15:55:21 Etc/GMT"))

Comment: Isn't the original purchase date always before the expiration date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

per apple documentation, one month subscription would expire in 5 minutes when you test it in sandbox environment. if you want to write/test some code around this, try to do within 5 mins.

Comment: thank you very much. I thought i was doing it the wrong way, this makes more sense